# NoMethodError in CommentsController#create undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, nomethoderror

NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
undefined method `comments'

This is the code in question. the @comment = current_user is the one raising the red flag.

```
def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@comment.post_id),
```

I'm following along with the book 'Rails Crash Course' and I am trying to allow a user to comment on a post but I get this error when I try to create a comment.

Comment: show your full stacktrace. Also, show the user and comment model.

Comment: Not enough info to answer your question.  Can you post your user and comment models?

Comment: Take a second look at your associations in the User model. Seem you've not added a "has_many :comments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `user.rb` it should have below

```
has_many :comments
```